# weak definition of a bool in block

Tags: objective-c, block

To define a weak references for objects in block i use something like this

```
MyViewController *__weak weakSelf= self;
UILabel *__weak weakLabel=ALabel;

///the block code with some examples
up2.completionBlock = ^(NSDictionary *headers, NSString *responseString) { 

   [weakSelf aMethodInTheController];
   [weakLabel setHidden:NO];


};
```

I have problem with a bool, how i can declare a weak reference to a bool to avoid the warnings "capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" ?
Not works with:

```
Bool *__weak weakFlag=Aflag;
```

Comment: What is `Bool`; that's not an Objective-C type?

Comment: What kind of object is a Bool?

Comment: I answered the question assuming it's a typo, but please correct it in the question or provide more information.

Comment: (A `BOOL` is a simple "scalar", like an `int`.  In fact, "under the covers", it is an `int`.  It is not an object pointer and hence does not need __weak or __strong or __smelly or any other such qualifier.)

Comment: PS:  It is *very critical* that you fully appreciate the difference between a pointer to something and "something" -- they are entirely different beasts.

Comment: Please show the line giving you the warning. Is the bool an instance variable of the same object, by any chance?

Comment: I believe jrturton is on the right track here. The thing being captured strongly is the 'self' in the implied 'self->Aflag'. Avoid that by using weakSelf->Aflag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not obvious what you are trying to do here.

There are two possibilities. Perhaps you need to pass a parameter to the block. So there is a variable of type `bool` or `BOOL` (they are similar for the purposes of this question) and you want to use it in the block.

Then, good news! You don't need anything at all. Just declare

```
  BOOL some_bool = (YES or NO or some calculation);
```

and use it later in the block. This works because Boolean types are primitive (they are some kind of integer) and not smart enough to participate in memory management. So the compiler doesn't worry much; it just grabs the value of this variable when the block is created and copies it into the block.

Here's [the relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html):

> Only the value is captured, unless you specify otherwise. This means that if you change the external value of the variable between the time you define the block and the time it’s invoked, ...

Alternatively, perhaps you want to have a variable which can take logical values and which can be changed by some other object in the time between you create the block and the time when it is run. In that case you need to

1. wrap boolean into `NSNumber`
2. store the strong reference to this `NSNumber` somewhere in your object
3. pass it as a weak pointer to the block

E.g.

```
// somewhere in the interface
@property NSNumber *someImportantFlag

 __weak NSNumber *weakFlag = someImportantFlag;
 ... ^{ ... if(weakFlag.boolValue) ... weakFlag = @(NO); ...}
```

Thanks to the commenters who made me reread the question and my answer.

Comment: How is this better than `BOOL` (there is no indication the value is going into a collection class)?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, both types have the same problem of being too primitive. I agree that `BOOL` is bit more widespread and has changed the example thusly.

Comment: Wrapping the value in an NSNumber only creates a storage management problem that didn't previously exist.

Comment: my case is the second, so i wrap my BOOL into a NSNumber, in this way the warnings disappears and i can manage my YES or NO value just like a normal BOOL

Comment: "Alternatively, perhaps you want to have a variable which can take logical values and which can be changed by some other object in the time between you create the block and the time when it is run." That doesn't make sense. How is using `NSNumber *` any better than just using `BOOL`?

Comment: `BOOL` is a C concept, so it cannot participate in the memory management of objective C. Instead of providing separate object wrappers (which could be called `NSBool`, ...) Apple wraps all of numbers into one `NSNumber`. Whether you really need objectified numbers, of course, depends upon your task.